# How to allow a user to save a IDBMutableFile from IndexedDB in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, indexeddb

I am currently using IndexedDB on Firefox to store the output of some file processing that is being done by a web worker. I have managed to get the finished file saved within  the IndexedDB as IDBMutableFile, however I can't seem to transfer the file as a blob to the web UI so that the user can download it.

When I read the file from the DB, I tried to use URL.createObjectURL to get a blob: link, however it seems like the file handle gets dereferenced as soon as the onsuccess handler exits (the blob is no longer accessible via a link).

I also tried to keep the file handle open using a FileReader, but that still  didn't work (I get a FileHandleInactiveError).

Any ideas?  The only thing that works seems to be to read the entire file as an arrayBuffer, and then create a new blob linked via URL.createObjectURL.  The problem is that the file is very large (1GB) and loading the entire thing into memory causes an NS_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY exception.

Here is the code:

```
// Retrieve the file that was just stored
transaction.objectStore("files").get("00b6ac47-7400-4894-8a76-de597c4d7b3e").onsuccess = function (event) {
    var fileHandle = event.target.result;
    var theFile = fileHandle.getFile();


    theFile.onsuccess = function() {
        var actualFile = this.result;

        // Get window.URL object
        var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(actualFile);

        // Set img src to ObjectURL
        var link = document.getElementById("blobLink");
        blobLink.setAttribute("href", blobUrl);

        //Problem: This link will point to a deleted blob in the UI
```